# How to add remoter computer into perfmon.msc?

Tags: remote-access, perfmon, windows

I want to add remote computer performance snap into local computer perfmon.msc.

Please help me out and provide step by step method.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this at the counter level, not as a snap-in.  When you are adding a counter in perfmon you'll have the option to add the counter using the local computer counters or using counters from a remote machine.  You don't need to add a separate machine as a full perfmon snap-in.

**Steps:**

- Open perfmon and click the + button to add a counter (or right-click and select "Add Counters...")
- Click the "Select counters from computer" radio button
- Type the name of the machine that you want to gather info from.
- Select the counters you wish to use in your trace

Comment: actually, I want to counters.
what are the steps?

Comment: @Syed: see my edit.